# Where in BitDefender does one change how it reacts when it detects something?

Tags: security, anti-virus, bitdefender

Where in BitDefender can one change that instead of automatically deleting infected files (or, to be more precise, the files which it thinks are infected) to ask the user what to do ?

---

I don't want to disable the warnings. **I want to disable him deleting my files.** And I don't know where to do that. I've looked through the "antivirus" side tab, and made custom setting on my own (4 options: take no action, disinfect, delete, move to quarantine <-- but I don't see where is the option to "ask the user what to do") ? ... so far about 30 of my files are deleted. I don't mind that the admin forcefully installed it, but I do mind that I had to restore those files from backup . (*yes, as you can tell, I don't like antiviruses ... they do more damage to my system than the alternative.* I've managed without them for 30 years now, and never had any problems. So far ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took From official page. BitDefender Forum > English > Business Protection > Enterprise Protection 3.x

You can disable those alerts by using the "Antivirus Settings" policy from the management console as follows:

1. In the BitDefender Management Console go to Policies --> Create New Policy
2. Open the "Antivirus Settings" policy template
3. Select the Protection Level "Custom"
4. Below, at Settings, uncheck the option "Show warning when a virus is found"
5. Click on Finish and assign the policy to the client computers where it should be applied.

**Or if this is a home version(just see your version comment do this)**

```
The option you are looking for is here:
- BitDefender Security Center (Advanced)
- Antivirus -> Shield
- click on Custom level
- uncheck Show warning when a virus is found
- click OK
```

Comment: Ah, I found it ... it was where your edit said it was under Shield/Custom/ when found "deny access and continue" ... but it still leaves missing the option to "ask the user".

Comment: Clarification: I want the warnings. I don't want the deletions of my files.

Comment: Search more options in that setting Route.                                                                Ok, that's all that I can do, until I have my main workstation in a couple of days,   if you consider just mark this answer as useful.

Comment: Fair enough. You certanly did your best to help! I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Before do the scan select from the action tab, **"Prompt user for action " OPTION**

Comment: Situation: I'm doing my work, browsing around in Windows Explorer ... open some folder, the popup jumps up and tells me it detected ... and deleted some file (which I needed). Where do I disable that kind of behaviour (atuomatic detection and deleting files) ?

Comment: Also, I can't find an action tab. Where is it ?

Comment: Which version of bitdefender are you using?

Comment: 2010 - Build: 13.0.19.347